# indexing in python numpy module

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

So, I'm new to python and learning about the NumPy module.
Here is my array

```
c = np.array([[[  0,   1,   2],
               [ 10,  12,  13]],
              [[100, 101, 102],
               [110, 112, 113]]])
```

in the above array if I try to access it through

```
c[:1,0:]
```

it produces expected output that

```
# expected because print from initial to row 1,0 excluding row 1,0
 array([[[ 0,  1,  2],  
         [10, 12, 13]]])
```

but now when I try to access it through

```
c[:1,1:]
```

it produces output that

```
array([[[10, 12, 13]]])
```

why???

Comment: It looks like your array has two arrays inside it, which numpy is reading as two rows. Was that your intention?

Comment: no, what I wanted to do was that, that it should produce output from initial row to final row eliminating the 1,1 row

Comment: so the output should be:(row0,0),(row0,1),(row1,0)

Comment: Please give your full expected output so we can understand what you are trying to do. I don't know what you mean when you say "excluding row 1,0".

Comment: array([[[  0,   1,   2],
        [ 10,  12,  13]],

       [[100, 101, 102]]])  # expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 3D array. You can check it with

```
print(c.shape)
```

that yields

```
(2, 2, 3)
```

Is 3D array really what you wish to do ?

If so, if you slice it with two indices instead of three, that means that the third is implicitly `:`. So `c[1, 1]` is equivalent to c[1, 1, :] which is equivalent to `c[1, 1, 0:3]`.

And your query `c[:1,1:]` is equivalent to `c[0, 1, 0:3]`: that is the correct result.

Now as per your comment I guess you wish to reshape, filter and reshape:

```
c.reshape(4, -1)[:3,:].reshape(1, 3, -1)
```

yields

```
array([[[  0,   1,   2],
        [ 10,  12,  13],
        [100, 101, 102]]])
```

Comment: yup 3d array slicing so if I want to produce output like      array([[[  0,   1,   2],
        [ 10,  12,  13]],

       [[100, 101, 102]]])                                then what should I do???

Comment: It is not possible in a single call: you need to combine the first one `c[:1,:,:]` with the second `c[1,:1,:]`, later. Or reshape the array first to 2D, then filter, then reshape to 3D if it makes sense.

Comment: So if I want to combine them then, how can I do that??? what does it mean to combine them???

Comment: I updated my answer above. I think that you need to really think in terms of shape. It is better to reshape a single array than to concatenate arrays, hence the solution above. Note that combining arrays is summing up one of their dimensions, and it can only work if ALL the other dimensions have the same lenght.